# Why are my text-less jquery UI buttons not square?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-theme

I am doing the following within a jQuery-UI themed fullCalendar:

```
var overlay = $('<div />');
   overlay.addClass(event.status);
   if(overlay.hasClass('pending')) {
      primaryIcon = 'ui-icon-check';
    } else {
      primaryIcon = 'ui-icon-cancel';
    }
    overlay.button({ icons: {
      primary: primaryIcon },
      text:false
    });

  overlay.css({
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'float': 'right'

  });
```

But my buttons look like this - http://cl.ly/2H1j3Z3i3G34271O2E2w

I also tried doing it without buttons and setting '.ui-state-default .ui-icon' on a span but the background did not show up. Anyone know what might be causing this?

I would like the buttons to be square like the first icon [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#icons) :

Comment: You may need the base css, http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css

Comment: Thanks, I tried that - made no difference.

Comment: i can't say, it's really a css issue and most likely not a jquery issue. jquery uses css for all the themeing, so if you leave something out, then it won't look right, but the javascript will still work, even though it might not seem like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add an addition style, `width:auto`:

```
overlay.css({
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'float': 'right',
    'width': 'auto'
});
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/Lu3GS/1/.

Looking at your code, you don't really require those to be actual buttons. If that's the case, you may consider using inline icons: http://jsfiddle.net/2U5TN/1/.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the button's width and height to be equal and I also set the font-size to zero (so the icon image would be in the center of the button). The CSS code is:

```
#your_button_id {
   position: relative; 
   font-size: 0; 
   width: 23px; 
   height: 23px;
}
```

In your case it would be:

```
overlay.css({
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'float': 'right',
    'width': '23px',
    'height': '23px',
    'font-size': '0'
});
```